# Laravel ManyToMany relations where to save item total?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship, laravel-6

Need advice what is best practice for Many To Many relations where to save item total column?
For ex. I have Users and Inventory Table, they are connected by pivot table and in pivot table i also have column total of attached Inventory. 
Is it correct way or can someone advice me which will be best way for it?

DB Structure

[image]

Comment: it's unclear how user and inventory are related. can you brief about the relationship?

Comment: For example My task: I have 10x  'A' inventory, and i want to give to user 5x 'A' from this 10, where i must to save this 5x quantity value?
I think save this inventory 5 times in pivot table will be incorrect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may suggest :

1) Make the pair of foreign keys unique (`user_id`, `inventory_id`) to prevent duplicates

2) Make a seperate model for you pivot table : `App\InventoryUser`

3) Make use of `updateOrCreate` Laravel Elequent function

According to [Elequent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) Docs

> updateOrCreate will update an existing model or create a new model if none
>   exists

E.g

```
$oldTotal = InventoryUser::where(['user_id' => 'x', 'inventory_id' => 'y'])->select('total') ?? 0;
$inventoryUser = InventoryUser::updateOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => 'x', 'inventory_id' => 'y'],
    ['total' => $oldTotal+1]
);
```

Or even better

```
$inventoryUser = InventoryUser::updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => 'x', 'inventory_id' => 'y']
)->increment('total'); // You must Set DEFAULT value to (0) for total column in your database
```

Comment: is it correct solution to store data in pivot table?

Comment: Yes it's ok, see the example provided by Laravel itself here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Is there a way to get data from a pivot table like `foreach ($user->inventory as $item) {
            
            $item->total;
        }` ?

Comment: Yes of course, However remember `many -- many` relationship ==  `1--many--1`. In other words you may define a relationship one to many between `User` Model and `InventoryUser` Pivot Model. 
Then you may access pivot data like : `$user->relationName->total`

Comment: Yes but, this user may have more than 1 related inventory. When i will make one to many relation and  will call $user->relationName->total it will return many inventory. I need to get for example how many(column total from pivot) x inventory have user.

Comment: For a particular inventory or for all of them ?

Comment: For a particular inevntory attached to user.

Comment: `$total = InventoryUser::where(['user_id' => 'x', 'inventory_id' => 'y'])->select('total');`

Comment: thanks will try in morning.

Comment: Did you gave it a try ?

Comment: Yes, and its works. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.